# Display only first three characters from a validation drop down list?

Tags: excel, validation

I am using a validation list in my cell E6 with the following options:

```
INS - Insurance
PBS - Public Safety
HRT - Health & Safety
```

When my user selects one of these options cell E6 will display like so:

```
"INS - Insurance"
```

However is there a way to trim the text to show only the first three characters in the cell like so:

```
INS
```

I have tried using a left function in my list source but this doesn't work. Any other ideas? Thanks

```
=LEFT("INS - INSURANCE",3)
```

Comment: Can you use VBA? would be super easy if so

Comment: The *validation list* restricts the *allowable* values in that cell, to the defined list of values. I don't think there's any way to do this even with a custom number format. You'll have to replace the literal value, and you could do this conceivably with a `Selection_Change` event procedure in the worksheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can use vba, simply add this event to Sheet1.

Change the Range("E6") to whatever your data validation range is.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E6")) Is Nothing and Target.CountLarge = 1 Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Target = Left(Target, 3)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```